# grep with regular expression

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I want to match all the lines that are of the below pattern in a file using `grep`.

```
Abc::xyz() [18-Feb-15 12:09:16]
```

I came up with below regex with grep , but it is not returning match.
Please help with the correct regex.

```
grep -E "^[:alnum:]::[:alnum:]\(\)[:space:]\[.*\]$" <file_name>
```

In python, below regex works , but not able to use the same with grep.

```
^.*::.*\(\) \[.*\]$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick with you one, use this:

```
grep -E "^[[:alpha:]]+::[[:alpha:]]+\(\)[[:space:]]\[.*\]$"
```

For example:

```
$ echo "Abc::xyz() [18-Feb-15 12:09:16]" | \
    grep -E "^[[:alpha:]]+::[[:alpha:]]+\(\)[[:space:]]\[.*\]$"
```

Output:

```
Abc::xyz() [18-Feb-15 12:09:16]
```

This can be made simpler:

```
grep -E "^[^:]+::[^(]+\(\) \[[^]]+\]$"
```

Check:

```
$ echo "Abc::xyz() [18-Feb-15 12:09:16]" | grep -E "^[^:]+::[^(]+\(\) \[[^]]+\]$"
Abc::xyz() [18-Feb-15 12:09:16]
```

Comment: not matching anything

Comment: @g4ur4v: working in my case..check my edits